# How do I find package names for java classes when I don't know what package it's in?

Tags: c#

What is an easy way to find what package to import when you know the name of the class, but don't know what package it's found in?

This drives me nuts, and I waste a lot of time. For example ... I have a bit of example code

```
    String[] people = wholeFile.Split(
        new String[] { Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine },
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    );
```

But I have no idea where to locate Environment or StringSplitOptions.

People post examples of code, and that's great. But I waste time trying to figure out what package holds the classes afterwards. In this case ... I couldn't figure it out at all. What's the use of code examples when you have no clue what package to import? No search I've found resolves where to find a class you know the name of, but not what package you have to import to use it.

I shouldn't have to post here and say "What package is so and so found in ..."

So, what package is StringSplitOptions found in ... and Environment ...

There has to be an easier way to resolve knowing a class name, but needing to find what package to import to use it.

Comment: I guess this depends a lot on what IDE you're using. NetBeans? Eclipse? JetBrains? The IDEs are the ones who offer suggestions and autocompletions.

Comment: Use an IDE and use the auto completion shortcut keys (often that is control--space)

Comment: Given the answer below it looks like they are not even java classes. So check the language first when looking at example code

Comment: I use th Google search string "java element docs" and it is at or near the top of the results.

Answer (score 7):

The code you've posted is C#, not Java. They have very similar syntax, so the mistake is understandable.

My usual solution to this problem is google. When I googled "java Environment.NewLine" the first result was a question about finding the Java equivalent for that in C#. I found something similar when googling "java StringSplitOptions". The only reasonable conclusion, then, is that this isn't Java code.